# Load raster from bytestream and set its CRS

Tags: python, amazon-s3, rasterio, bytestream

What I want to do : load a raster from an s3 bucket in memory and set its CRS to 4326 (it has no crs set)

What I have so far:

```
import boto3
import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS

bucket = 'my bucket'
key = 'my_key'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file_byte_string = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)['Body'].read()
with rasterio.open(BytesIO(file_byte_string), mode='r+') as ds:
  crs = CRS({"init": "epsg:4326"}) 
  ds.crs = crs
```

I have found the way to structure my code here

[Set CRS for a file read with rasterio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985957/set-crs-for-a-file-read-with-rasterio)

It works if I give it a path to a local file but it does not work for bytestreams.

The error I get when I have '+r' mode:

`rasterio.errors.PathError: invalid path '<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb4503ca4d0>'`

The error I get when I have 'r' mode:

`rasterio.errors.DatasetAttributeError: read-only attribute`

Is there a way to load bytestream in r+ mode so that I can set/modify the CRS?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am on the same issue right now

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I solved this by declaring `ds.crs = crs` on the destination file. it is not a clever workaround

Comment: Better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this if you wrap your bytes in a `NamedTemporaryFile`. This and some alternatives are explained [in the docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/memory-files.html).

```
import boto3
import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS
import tempfile

bucket = 'asdf'
key = 'asdf'


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file_byte_string = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)['Body'].read()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    tmpfile.write(file_byte_string)
    with rasterio.open(tmpfile.name, "r+") as ds:
         crs = CRS({"init": "epsg:4326"}) 
         ds.crs = crs
```

An important limitation of this approach is that you have to download the whole file into memory from S3, as opposed to mounting the file remotely like [this](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/vsi.html#aws-s3).